How to fix "reading directory: Invalid argument"?
$ ls Downloads
ls: reading directory 'Downloads': Invalid argument

How can I ever again access my precious Downloads directory? I've got something important in there!
What next, a ransom note? I've got work to do. No time for fun and games.
Seen on ChromeOS.

Do not panic. You have saved a file with too long a name.
$ ls Downloads/|wc -l
596
$ touch Downloads/$(perl -we 'print 8 x 255')
$ ls Downloads/|wc -l
ls: reading directory 'Downloads/': Invalid argument
0
$ rm Downloads/$(perl -we 'print 8 x 255')
$ ls Downloads/|wc -l
596

So simply remove the file with too long a name, as shown above.

But I cannot do ls, so I cannot see what name to remove!

You didn't remember what the filename was?

I did, but it was so long, I don't remember each word.

Well, OK, go into the ChromeOS files app, you can still find it there,
and remove or rename it to something shorter.

Thanks! You're a lifesaver!

In fact people told them their OS had a problem.
I'll try to tell them again.

You are so cool, but when I tried 8 x 256 it said "File name too long" so couldn't recreate the problem.

Ah, at 256 ChromeOS's 2nd layer of protection prevents you from recreating the bug. Note I used 255.

Amazing. So the danger zone is somewhere between 2xx and 255?

Probably. Maybe even 1xx..255. Let's give others a chance to find the lower limit of the danger zone.

Yeah! Got it! Hey wait. Why did I suddenly get into this life threatening mess?

You probably saved some long_webpage_name.mhtml . Yes, ChromeOS clips the name at 256, but as you see that still leaves Linux ls unusable! One would expect a better product from such a large company.
So next time when browsing the web with Chrome on ChromeOS, think long and hard when hitting CTRL+S about what your uncle Dan told you the bug we discussed.

Sure will!

